# simple but challenging regular expression. extracting multiple expressions. (google sheets)

Tags: regex, google-sheets, expression

I've been trying to solve this problem for hours! I've looked around at other questions, but no one seems to have given a good answer. Basically, I'm trying to extract 2 similar expressions from a string of text, as an array, and not return an error if there is only one such expression in the string of text...I've attached a spreadsheet with the exact problem...Any ideas?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1b-mvMMgG37IVzHPBZUmFmPcSfXMt7RAtHNuxFd5lN5k/edit?usp=sharing

For example, write an expression such that we return an array, "abc" and  "xyz". The requirement is that the same expression works for all strings of text (as in does not return an error). And we need to use regextract, not any other function. Is it possible? Maybe not

These are the strings to extract from:

abc 123 xyz

abc 123

123 qrs

Comment: Please include the details of your question in your question, not in an external document.  It would be helpful to show examples of strings to match and the expected results.  These should all be include in the question as text, not images or links.

Comment: Oh ok sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that your notes on the doc say it has to be regexextract and no other formula but by wrapping a regexreplace formula within your regexextract, this will dynamically do exactly what you are asking:

=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,REGEXREPLACE(A1,"([A-Za-z]+)","($1)"))

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Can you explain this to me a bit? What are you doing with the ($1)?

Comment: Oh i see. Are you using the regexreplace to put all relevant strings in capture groups, and then just extracting the capture groups? Clever!

Comment: Yes exactly. I really love the regex functions in sheets i literally use  them on a daily basis for wrangling, cleaning, extracting data.

Comment: Can you use that kind of reference '($1)' within a single regular expression as well? or no

Comment: As far as i know you can really only use it in regex replace because you build the capture groups in the regex you want to extract.  I could totally be wrong but to my knowledge  if i understand the question properly